# Search Center in sharepoint 2016 online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Are Search service and Search Center configured by default in SharePoint 2016 Online?

Can Search Center and Search scope help to search across site collections? How in SharePoint Online?

Will cross site publishing help here?

Scenario is: 3 site collections. 1 is Intranet which searches other content in the other 2 site collections.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Search service is preconfigured for every tenant in SharePoint Online.
Yes you can, By Default SharePoint search page will return all contents from all site collection when you select **"All Sites"** refiner